# Why ANTLR4 parsers accumulates ATNConfig objects?

Tags: antlr4

When developing a Parser for C++ using ANTLR, we made a batch parsing test case where a new parser is constructed to parse each C++ source file. The performance is acceptable at start - about 15 seconds per file. But after parsing some 150+ files the parsing of each file takes longer and longer and finally jvm throws a "GC limit exceeded" error.

Using JProfiler we found there are many ATNConfig objects being accumulated progressively after parsing each file. Starting from about 70M, they steadily pile up to beyond 500M until the heap is near full and GC takes 100% CPU time. The biggest objects (those that retain the most objects in heap) recognized by JProfiler include a DFA[] and a PredictionContextCache.

One thing to note is that we used 2 threads to run the parsing tasks concurrently. Although the threads don't share any parser or parse tree objects, we notice there are static fields in use by the parser generated by ANTLR, which may contribute to the memory issue in a multi-thread setup. Anyway it is just a suspect.

Does anyone have a clue what's the cause of "ATNConfig being accumulated"? Is there a solution already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ATNConfig` instances are used for the dynamic DFA construction at runtime. The number of instances required is a function of the grammar and input. There are a few solutions available:

1. Increase the amount of memory you provide to the application. Try `-Xmx12g` as a starting point to see if the problem is too little memory for the application.
2. Each `ATNConfig` belongs to a `DFA` instance which represents the DFA for a  particular decision. If you know the decision(s) which contain the most `ATNConfig` instances, you can work to simplify those decisions in the grammar.
3. Periodically clear the cached DFA, by calling `Recognizer.clearDFA()`. Note that clearing the DFA too often will hurt performance (if possible, do not clear the DFA at all).
4. You can use the "optimized" fork of the ANTLR 4. This fork of the project is designed to reduce the memory footprint, which can tremendously help performance for complicated grammars at the expense of speed for certain simple grammars.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam. We solved the problem for now following your 3rd solution. (We didn't find Reognizer.clearDFA() in ANTLR 4.2 that we are using, but making our own clearDFA() did the magic.)

Comment: I'm particularly interested in how to "know the decision(s) which contain the most `ATNConfig` instances" and how to "simplify my grammar". Would you please point me to some related documents/resources?

Comment: Long time Sam.  :)  How does one find "the decision(s) which contain the most ATNConfig instances"?